# Issue setting up a contact form widget with the workflow module: Produces Uncaught TypeError

Tags: apostrophe-cms

When adding a contact form widget using apostrophe with the workflow module, the widget addition produces an error on the frontend.

Please see the console error output below:

```
user.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'workflowLocale' of undefined
    at self.beforePopulate (user.js:10)
    at wrapper (lodash.js:3772)
    at async.js:718
    at iterate (async.js:262)
    at async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (async.js:281)
    at _parallel (async.js:717)
    at Object.async.series (async.js:739)
    at Object.self.populate (user.js:24)
    at Object.self.play (always.js:15)
    at HTMLDivElement.enhance (always.js:56)
```

I tried using the tutorial instructions exactly from main website, the error is still produced: https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html#going-deeper-with-apostrophe-creating-a-code-contact-form-code-module

The code was also tested with the excludeType feature, but no luck:

```
'apostrophe-workflow': {
    alias: 'workflow',
    excludeTypes: 'contact-form'
},
```

The contact form widget does work on a standard install of apostrophe without the workflow module installed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you encounter this problem when using the `apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets` module? This is essentially the contact forms tutorial already packaged as a working module.

Comment: Hi Tom, setting up the form using the apostrophe-pieces-submit-widgets works when using the workflow module. I no longer get the error mentioned above and the posting of the form is now successful.

Thank you!